Instagram Login Automation Testing with Selenium and Java
I'm new to software testing and below is the code for the automation testing. Although the automation testing steps are done in chrome correctly, the message is displayed as testing is failed. I run this on IntelliJ. How can I fix that?
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class testCase {
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void google() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.name("Search")).sendKeys("Instagram" + Keys.ENTER);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login")).click();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("username" + Keys.ENTER);

        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("password");
    }
}

Edit: This is the error message I receive:
 Test ignored. 
=============================================== 
Default Suite Total tests run: 1, Passes: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 1 Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0 
=============================================== 
Process finished with exit code 0


Update the question with exact error stacktrace.
